# Own authentication service uses too late

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, felogin

Once again I created my own authentication service. This is registered and is also called. After submitting the login form (EXT:felogin) you get back to the same page - but Felogin continues to show the login form. After a page reload, the logged-in state is recognized correctly and the status display is displayed.
The same form works correctly with a normal, local FE user.

When debugging `authUser()` correctly returns `200`.

What could that be?

Answer (score 0):

Besides returning `200` by `authUser()`, having a valid FE-User (at least with uid, pid, username, usergroup) is necessary. My FE-User was broken.

[TYPO Documentation - Authentication services](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-services/7.6/en-us/Authentication/Index.html#developing-an-authentication-service):

> One important thing to know is that the TYPO3 CMS authentication process needs to have users inside database records (“fe_users” or “be_users”).